# Laravel where clause is ambiguous

Tags: sql, laravel

Estoy obteniendo este error y no consigo la solución. Sé que tiene que ver con que dos tablas tienen el mismo nombre pero no se como solucionarlo correctamente.

El error:

message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'empresa_id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `servicios`.*, `categoria`.`nombre_categoria` from `servicios` inner join `categoria` on `categoria`.`id` = `servicios`.`categoria_id` where `categoria_id` in (18) and `empresa_id` = 8)"

El método:

```
public function obtenerServicioPersonal(Request $request){
    $filaProfesional = ProfesionalModel::where('empresa_id', Auth::user()->empresa_id)->get();
    for($i=0; $i<=count($request['categoria_id'])-1; $i++){
        for($e=0; $e<=count($filaProfesional)-1; $e++){
            $filaComision = json_decode($filaProfesional[$e]->comision_profesional, true);
            if(isset($filaComision['comision'][$request['categoria_id'][$i]])){
                $profesional_id[] = $filaProfesional[$e]->id;
                $datos['profesionalDB']['id'][] = $filaProfesional[$e]->id;
                $datos['profesionalDB']['nombre_profesional'][] = $filaProfesional[$e]->nombre_profesional;
                $datos['profesionalDB']['apellido_profesional'][] = $filaProfesional[$e]->apellido_profesional;
                $datos['categoria_id'][] = $request['categoria_id'][$i];
            }
        }
    }
    if(!isset($profesional_id)){
        $datos['categoria_id'] = [];
        $datos['profesionalDB']['id'] = [];
    }
    $datos['servicioDB'] = ServiciosModel::select('servicios.*', 'categoria.nombre_categoria')->join('categoria', 'categoria.id', 'servicios.categoria_id')->whereIn('categoria_id', $request['categoria_id'])->where('empresa_id', Auth::user()->empresa_id)->get();
    $datos['filaCategoria'] = CategoriaModel::whereIn('id', $request['categoria_id'])->where('empresa_id', Auth::user()->empresa_id)->get();
    ClienteModel::where('id', 1)->update(['servicio_cliente' => json_encode(['categoria' => [1, 9], 'servicio' => [4], 'profesional' => [4]])]);

    return $datos;
}
```

Agradecería todo tipo de sugerencia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El mensaje quiere decir que (muy probablemente) tanto la tabla servicios como la tabla categoria, tienen un campo `empresa_id`, y básicamente al hacer la consulta, no sabe el campo de qué tabla tomar.

Para resolverlo, agrega la tabla (como lo haces en otra parte de la consulta) antes del campo:

```
...->where('tabla.empresa_id', Auth::user()->empresa_id)
```

Comment: Agregué la table y me sale el siguiente error: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. Sin embargo la ruta es POST y la llamada a este método también es post. $.ajax({
   url: "{{url('/obtenerServicioPersonal/')}}",
   type: "POST",

Comment: Eso parece ser un problema distinto, el cual está fuera del alcance de esta pregunta.

Comment: Agradezco mucho la clarificación que me brindaste. Veré como lo resuelvo y si no generaré otra pregunta entonces. Nuevamente gracias!